# OnClick change button text and URL

Tags: javascript, css

I have this HTML code that works as expected. When the user clicks on "Start" button, the button text should change to stop (along with href to stop_api)

How do I accomplish this? Pushing the stop button should change the text back to Start if stop_api response was "success". The code mentioned above is an example. I just need a button to hit the api. This is simple GUI for new users.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>start activity</h2>
  <a href="https://link_to_start_api"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Start</button> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit and add relevant JS you attempted - you obviously need to call the API somehow

Comment: You should not nest a `<button>` element inside an `<a>` element.

Comment: `<a class="btn btn-danger">Start</a>`

Comment: If it follows the link it is not going to stay on the current page sonot sure how the text is supposed to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a form being submitted, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to link to another page.

```js
const submitButton = document.querySelector('form button')
const form = document.querySelector('form')

const start = 'Start'
const stop = 'Stop'

const startApiEndpoint = 'https://link_to_start_api'
const stopApiEndpoint = 'https://link_to_stop_api'

// Listen for form submit
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (submitButton.textContent.includes(start)) {
    api(startApiEndpoint)
    submitButton.textContent = stop
  } else {
    api(stopApiEndpoint)
    submitButton.textContent = start
  }
})

// Hit api endpoint and do something with the response
function api(endpoint) {
  console.log(`Fetching ${endpoint}`)
  fetch(endpoint)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      // Check for success and update button text
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<form class="container">
  <h2>start activity</h2>
  <button class="btn btn-danger">Start</button>
</form>
```

It's probably a better idea to wait for a successful response from each api call before changing the behaviour/UI of the form.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a second button next to the existing one with an display of none. When the user presses the button, switch the `display:none` off and enable `display:none` on your current start button

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, I recommend using a different id though

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>start activity</h2>
      <a href="https://link_to_start_api"> <button id="start" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Start</button> </a>
    </div>
<script> 
 var button = document.getElementById("start") 
 button.onclick = function(){
    button.innerHTML = 'Stop'
}

</script>
```